# Validation for 4-digit numbers with one decimal place

Tags: jquery, regex, expression, jquery-validate

I am trying to create a jquery validation for number.

It should allow 4 digit first and then after decimal point it should allow 1 digit.

For decimal my code is working fine:

```
$.validator.addMethod('Decimal', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9,\d{4}]+(\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(value); 
  }, "Please enter a correct number, format xxxx.X");
```

I may be making mistake in regular expression.

Comment: Are you looking for `/^[\d]{4}(\.\d)?$/`? This requires the input to be either **xxxx** or **xxxx.X**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exactly ***NNNN.N*** *(1234.5)* use:

```
/^\d{4}\.\d$/
```

For optional ***.N*** *(1234 1234. 1234.5)* go with:

```
/^\d{4}(\.\d?)?$/
```

For numbers up to size of ***NNNN.N*** *(1 .5 12.5 123. 1234 1234.5)* go with:

```
/^(?=.*\d)\d{0,4}(\.\d?)?$/
```

And if you want to allow +/- at the beginning, then replace `^` with `^[-+]?`.

Comment: @Amit - String `.8` does match - test: `alert(".8".match(/^(?=.*\d)\d{0,4}(\.\d?)?$/) != null);` at http://jsfiddle.net/UcSm9/